# Comparing string in C

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char array1 [50];
char array2 [50];
printf("enter a string:\n");
fgets(array1, 50, stdin);
printf("enter a string2:\n");
fgets(array2, 50, stdin);
if (array1==array2){
    printf("True");
}
```

}

If I enter the same string twice this code should print true. However it doesn't. How do I fix this?

Comment: Arrays are pointer. Your `==` compares the address locations and not the char elements

Comment: @Micka: No, arrays are not pointers. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www..c-faq.com). You're correct that `array1==array2` does a pointer comparison, but only because the array expressions are *converted* to pointers.

Comment: use the function [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/). This link is for C++, but works the same in C.

Comment: @eventHandler: Why `strncmp` rather than `strcmp`?

Comment: yeah that's better. i was comparing some kind of strings yesterday using strncmp. got confused. [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) suits better for this.

Comment: Shall it be a byte-string, aka no interpretation except for the terminator, or text in some encoding like UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

To compare strings you can use `strcmp` it is defined in [`string.h`](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#strcmp)

`array1` and `array2` are pointers to the start of the strings. thus this code `array1==array2` compares pointers not the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcmp` like

```
 if (!strcmp(array1,array2))
    printf("true\n");
```

See [strcmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)

Your comparison `array1 == array2` is comparing *addresses* (so does not work).

Comment: IMHO `if (strcmp(array, array2) != 0)` is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the two pointers to the memory location of the arrays.

You can use `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(str1,str2) == 0) {
    printf("they match!");
}
```

Or in more detail, you need to compare the value of each entry in the arrays:

```
int i;
int match = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    if (array1[i] != array2[i]) {
        match = 0;
        break;
    }
}
if (match == 1) {
    printf("They match");
} else {
    printf("They do not match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two pointers there. You want `strncmp(array1, array2, 50) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strcmp` or `strncmp`.

For example:

`int result = strncmp(string1, string2, compareLimit);`, where `compareLimit` is the number of characters to compare to.

The `result` will inform you on equality `0` or whether `string1` is greater than, or less than `string2`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by the same. Do you want the exact same byte sequence, or a locale-dependend comparison?

The first one is handled be `strcmp()`, the second calls for `strcoll()`. Both are in `<string.h>`.